# How to properly do detrending for the multidimensional Fourier transform?

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, fourier-analysis, computer-science, computational-mathematics

Detrending as described [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4748914/does-this-gradient-adjusting-variant-of-the-fft-have-a-name?noredirect=1#comment10077097_4748914) is a useful technique used as a preprocessor for the Fast Fourier Transform.

However how can it best be applied in a multidimensional case?

---

**Own work:**
What I have tried for 2 Dimensional functions is

1. Apply detrending in dimension 1
2. Apply detrending in dimension 2
3. Apply FFT dimension 1
4. Apply FFT dimension 2

What happens here is that after step 2 of detrending the detrending done in step 1 can become "scrambled" or "undone" in some sense of the word as a gradient is applied orthogonally which skews the data once more. Still it performs a lot better than doing nothing (for my application anyway).